# Is this vala code a memory leak?

Tags: memory-leaks, vala

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2270511/398460)

> Vala doesn't have garbage collection. It does reference counting.

I'm not exactly sure what the difference is between garbage collection and reference counting nor could I find a clear explanation.
Do I explicitly need to delete bmp and/or add a destructor to class Bmp? 
IOW: does this code have a memory leak?

```
public void* run() {
    while(true) {
        if(detected) {
            ...
            var bmp = new Bmp(800,800);
            ...

public class Bmp {
    ...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code you have written is not a memory leak, but it is possible to write one. For instance:

```
   class Foo {
       Foo? f;
   }
   var foo1 = new Foo();
   var foo2 = new Foo();
   foo1.f = foo2;
   foo2.f = foo1;
```

Every time a `Foo` is assigned, a counter for that instance is incremented and decremented when it is unassigned. Because `foo1` and `foo2` have references to each other, their counts will never go to zero, even if there are no references to them in the rest of the program. The `unowned` keyword makes a reference that not counted. So, a dangling pointer can be written as follows:

```
var foo = new Foo();
unowned Foo f = foo;
foo = null;
// f now refers to an object that has been deallocated.
```

If your object graph has no cycles, there will be no problem. If you have any circular references, you may leak memory if you do not clean up properly.